# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' error in Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I install the missing package? I have read all possible answers and none of them worked for me :)

I'm gettting an error while deploying to azure webapp. I have a simple web application which is properly working on localhost and when I deploy it on azure, I get the flask_sqlalchemy module not found error.

I have properly created the azure web app and tested with a simple flask hello world and it works. I get the error when I include flask_sqlalchemy package, the error is:

```
Container adbv1_0_dc3e289f couldn't be started: Logs = 2021-06-17T18:05:03.086995675Z 
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087028275Z   _____                               
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087033575Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087037475Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087050475Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087055275Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087059275Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087062875Z 
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087066175Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087069575Z 
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087072775Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087076175Z Python 3.7.9
2021-06-17T18:05:03.087079575Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2021-06-17T18:05:03.288106144Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2021-06-17T18:05:03.337564410Z App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect
2021-06-17T18:05:03.344405319Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -bindPort 8000
2021-06-17T18:05:03.372748657Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2021-06-17T18:05:03.372804757Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2021-06-17T18:05:03.372811157Z Build Operation ID: dcddb3cf-1d35-498a-a761-e3406dd43c12
2021-06-17T18:05:04.477776233Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20210420.1, Commit: 85c6e9278aae3980b86cb1d520aaad532c814ed7, ReleaseTagName: 20210420.1
2021-06-17T18:05:04.681032904Z Detected an app based on Flask
2021-06-17T18:05:04.682204606Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
2021-06-17T18:05:05.096980460Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2021-06-17T18:05:05.554970271Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2021-06-17T18:05:05.560535178Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
2021-06-17T18:05:08.084237043Z [2021-06-17 18:05:08 +0000] [35] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-06-17T18:05:08.123152295Z [2021-06-17 18:05:08 +0000] [35] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (35)
2021-06-17T18:05:08.131002505Z [2021-06-17 18:05:08 +0000] [35] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-06-17T18:05:08.206255905Z [2021-06-17 18:05:08 +0000] [38] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 38
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241408615Z [2021-06-17 18:05:10 +0000] [38] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241442915Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241448815Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241453315Z     worker.init_process()
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241457515Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241473615Z     self.load_wsgi()
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241477715Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241481515Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241485115Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241489015Z     self.callable = self.load()
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241492715Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241496515Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241500115Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241504315Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241508015Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241511815Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241515515Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241519315Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241523015Z   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241527115Z   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241531815Z   File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241535715Z   File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241539515Z   File "", line 728, in exec_module
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241543315Z   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241547215Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 5, in 
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241551315Z     from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241555015Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
2021-06-17T18:05:10.241558715Z [2021-06-17 18:05:10 +0000] [38] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 38)
2021-06-17T18:05:11.199763690Z [2021-06-17 18:05:11 +0000] [35] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-06-17T18:05:11.244026549Z [2021-06-17 18:05:11 +0000] [35] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I have also properly created the azure sql database with access to azure app services and added my ip address.

I have tried installing the packages using
pip install -r requirements.txt from the kudu terminal and it gets stucked, this is the message I get.

```
/home>cd site/wwwroot
/home/site/wwwroot>pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting flask_sqlalchemy==2.4.1
  Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy==1.3.11
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.11.tar.gz (6.0 MB)
Collecting Flask==1.0.2
  Downloading Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.10
  Downloading Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==0.14.1
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (322 kB)
Collecting pyodbc==4.0.27
  Downloading pyodbc-4.0.27.tar.gz (242 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting click>=5.1
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for sqlalchemy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyodbc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, sqlalchemy, Flask, pyodbc, flask-sqlalchemy
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: started
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: finished with status 'done'
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'>
```

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import csv
import os
import urllib
import datetime
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = 'False'

# Configure Database URI for azure sql
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER="myservername".database.windows.net;DATABASE="mydbname";UID="myuid";PWD="Mypassword"")

# initialization
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class table(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column('_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    time = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return "Hello"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is how my requirements.txt file looks like:

```
Flask>=1.0,<=1.1.2
azure-storage-blob
azure-identity
flask_sqlalchemy==2.4.1
pyodbc
```

My file Structure for the app:

[image: File Structure for the app]

Comment: I have tried that as well. It gives me the same error. I had used pip freeze > requirements.txt to generate the package name, it is not working as well.

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: How are you deploying your app? Jason Pan's answer reminded me that I had to use the `ubuntu-18.04` container image, not the latest image.

Answer (score 0):

Run below cmd on ssh, after restarting, check if your webapp is back to normal.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install g++
apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy
// I carefully read your log pyodbc and it seems that it was not installed successfully. 
apt-get install unixodbc-dev
pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: I couldn't open ssh with the above code as it had an error. So I stripped it down with no libraries and just displayed hello world, once that was working, I was able to access SSH terminal. After that I installed all the packages and also tried importing the packages in python3 console and it worked but the error remains when I try to deploy it :(

Answer (score 0):

You should install prerequisites described [here](http://%20https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#install-from-source).

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt install -y build-essential python3-dev libpq-dev
$ pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: link is invalid